# How do you detect when a Polymer page section is showing?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm building a Polymer (SPA) app and have created each of my `iron-pages` sections as a `<dom-module>`. Because they all share the same `paper-toolbar` I would like to add some toolbar buttons on a certain page but not have them appear on others.

In Polymer there are `ready`, `created`, `attached` and `detached` functions which all fire off when the app loads. Is there an event for 'page will appear' or 'page will disappear' so I can add toolbar buttons unique to that page then remove them again once the page changes? Here's what I've got have so far:

Index.html snippet

```
<main class="content">
  <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="login" >
    <!-- login page -->
    <section data-route="login">
      <page-login></page-login>
    </section>
    <!-- home page -->
    <section data-route="home">
      <page-home></page-home>
    </section>
  </iron-pages>
</main>
```

page-home.html page

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="page-home">
<template>
<h1>Home</h1>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: "page-home",
  ready : function() {
    console.log(this.localName + ' ready');
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + ' was created');
  },
  attached: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + ' was attached');
    //this._activateToolBarButtons();
  },
  detached: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + ' was detached');
    //this._deactivateToolBarButtons();
  },
  _activateToolBarButtons : function() {
    // show toolbar buttons unique to this page...
  },
  _deactivateToolBarButtons : function() {
    // hide toolbar buttons unique to this page...
  }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iron-pages implements the IronSelectableBehavior.

This means that the 'iron-select' and 'iron-deselect' event is thrown when an item is set/unset as selected.

There is no reason to have a  element as a direct child. You could simply use the custom element.

```
<main class="content">
  <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="login" >
    <!-- login page -->
      <page-login data-route="login"></page-login>
    <!-- home page -->
      <page-home data-route="home"></page-home>
  </iron-pages>
</main>
```

Then understanding that those elements are purpose built for being placed as a child of the iron-pages element, use DOM accessors to get the parent element, which would be the iron-page tag. Then add an event listener for iron-select and iron-deselect to notify your custom elements and change the toolbar.

Comment: So in the iron-page dom-module Polymer `ready` script it would be `this.parentNode.addEventListener("iron-select", this.ironSelect)` and you can get the current page with a method `ironSelect: function(e){ var page = e.target.selected; }`

Comment: I also found out you can do this by implementing routes using Page.js for example - I could also post this solution if anyone else wants it.

Comment: Page.js is useful for basic SPA page routing. It's not a full routing solution. But great to get started.

Answer (score 7):

It appears in addition to `ready`, `created`, `attached` and `detached` functions in Polymer 1.0 there is also an `attributeChanged` function and you can use this to detect page attribute class was changed to `iron-selected`.

```
Polymer({
    is: "page-home",
    attributeChanged: function(name, type) {
        console.log(this.localName + ' attribute ' + name + ' was changed to ' + this.getAttribute(name));
    },
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it. A little more decoupled than the accepted answer.